# How can we sort threads on Linux by their System CPU (not the overall or User CPU)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu

Top can be used to sort processes/threads by overall CPU. How about sorting  threads just by their system CPU? I am trying to investigate a case of high system CPU on a server, and strace gives me the breakup of system time in terms of system calls made by a thread. But, how does one identify the thread that contributes the most to System CPU (the thread that makes the most expensive syscalls, essentially)?

Answer (score 0):

syscalls as reported by strace may or may not have correlation with the time spent *actively* doing something in the kernel. In fact you don't want to look at this most of the time.

What you want instead is a flamegraph and go from there. In particular, it may be kernel is spending a lot of time not even executing any syscalls in the first place.

http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html